# How to encrypt Ubuntu 18.04 after installation?

Tags: 18.04, encryption, home-directory

Unfortunately, Ubuntu 18.04 does not offer an encryption option when installing.

As I travel with my laptop from time to time, I'd like to encrypt (at least) my home folder.

There are dozens of (outdated) tutorials out there.

I'd like to know how what is the current best practice.

Comment: Ubuntu installation step: "[Installation type](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5)", gives the user the option to "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" with sub-option of "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security" 
Doing it after the install is less than optimal.

Comment: Please see my comment to the K7AAY's answer.

Comment: You can encrypt the home directory after installation with 16.04, but not 18.04. Detail for 16.04 follows below.

For 18.04, due to a change documented in http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1756840 , reinstallation with full disk encryption is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the home directory after installation with 16.04, but not 18.04. Detail for 16.04 follows below. For 18.04, due to a change documented in http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1756840 , reinstallation with full disk encryption is the best practice.

--

For 16.04 /home directory encryption, following [these steps](https://helpdesk.eoas.ubc.ca/kb/articles/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu), which require logging in as another user (said user, if you don't have another user, can be deleted after the encryption):

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup
```

'user' below should be replaced with your own username

```
sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u user
```

1. You must log in as the other user account immediately – before a reboot!
2. A copy of your original home directory was made. You can restore the backup directory
   if you lose access to your files.
3. You should generate and record a recovery phrase.
4. You should encrypt your swap partition, too, as a next-to-last step, with `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap`
5. Clean up.

Log out and log back in as your original user account. Do not reboot your system before logging back in!  It will prompt you to copy a Recovery Passphrase which should be saved in multiple places outside of the PC and zealously guarded.

You’ll have to remove the backup directory from a terminal with a command like the following one. Be very careful when using this command – you could accidentally delete your real home folder or another important system directory if you type the directory name wrong: `sudo rm -rf /home/user.random`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was 100% sure there was no option to encrypt at configuration/installation time - which maybe was because I ordered a Dell XPS with Ubuntu. Back then, I even called the Dell hotline which told me it is no longer possible to encrypt Ubuntu at installation ( https://bartongeorge.io/2018/07/27/the-xps-13-developer-edition-goes-bionic-welcome-18-04/#comment-139662 ). Also in this issue at the Ubuntu tracker it is mentioned that the encryption of the home directory was removed from the installer. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1756840

Comment: The link you provide to the encryption post installation mentions only Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. Are you sure this works with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: If you're not wedded to the installation you have (and have zero or easy backup to do), I would still opt for a clean install, selecting the "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security" option... particularly given the tidy and rapid install time compared to Fenêtres (windows?!)